# When should PhoneGap build be used?

Tags: cordova, mobile

I'm very confused as to when one should actually use PhoneGap Build. It seems to take a long time to build and therefore would seem impractical to develop using it, but I'm not sure.

So, should you use PhoneGap Build whenever you want to run/debug your application or only when you want to deploy your app to the app stores (so you could develop it with the Android tools, for example, and then it would be converted to work with all supported devices).

Answer (score 3):

PhoneGap Build should be used whenever you want to build your application for multiple platforms in one go. Yes, PhoneGap build is slow but the advantage is where you don't have to manage SDKs for each platform to build.

It's MUCH easier to debug an application when it's run locally. You cannot afford to wait for PhoneGap Build to build your application each time you make a change and want to see if it's working.

So you are correct. It's impractical to use it for local development. However, in a case where you cannot find an Apple Mac to develop the iOS version of your app, PhoneGap build can be helpful. See [how to do a debug build](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/phonegap-debug). This seems to be using [Apache Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/).